# Rails console error: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Any attempt to run `rails console` in the root directory of my Rails application produces the following error:

> undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

The full stack trace:

```
 /Users/gnerkus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@rails-experiments/gems/railties-5.0.0.beta1.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:245:in `each_registered_block': undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
  from /Users/gnerkus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@rails-experiments/gems/railties-5.0.0.beta1.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:224:in `run_console_blocks'
  from /Users/gnerkus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@rails-experiments/gems/railties-5.0.0.beta1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:461:in `block in run_console_blocks'
  from /Users/gnerkus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@rails-experiments/gems/railties-5.0.0.beta1.1/lib/rails/engine/railties.rb:13:in `each'
  from /Users/gnerkus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@rails-experiments/gems/railties-5.0.0.beta1.1/lib/rails/engine/railties.rb:13:in `each'
  from /Users/gnerkus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@rails-experiments/gems/railties-5.0.0.beta1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:461:in `run_console_blocks'
  from /Users/gnerkus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@rails-experiments/gems/railties-5.0.0.beta1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:442:in `load_console'
  from /Users/gnerkus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@rails-experiments/gems/railties-5.0.0.beta1.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:34:in `initialize'
  from /Users/gnerkus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@rails-experiments/gems/railties-5.0.0.beta1.1/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `new'
  from /Users/gnerkus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@rails-experiments/gems/railties-5.0.0.beta1.1/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
  from /Users/gnerkus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@rails-experiments/gems/railties-5.0.0.beta1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
  from /Users/gnerkus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@rails-experiments/gems/railties-5.0.0.beta1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
  from /Users/gnerkus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@rails-experiments/gems/railties-5.0.0.beta1.1/lib/rails/command.rb:20:in `run'
  from /Users/gnerkus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@rails-experiments/gems/railties-5.0.0.beta1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
  from bin/rails:4:in `require'
  from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I've traced the error to this block in the `railtie.rb` file in the Rails lib:

```
def each_registered_block(type, &block)
  klass = self.class
  while klass.respond_to?(type)
    # The ':console' type doesn't seem to exist
    klass.public_send(type).each(&block) 
    klass = klass.superclass
  end
end
```

which in turn comes from this block:

```
def run_console_blocks(app) #:nodoc:
  each_registered_block(:console) { |block| block.call(app) }
end
```

I uninstalled the `spring` gem and installed the `rubocop` gem. Otherwise, my `Gemfile` contains the default gems.

My Ruby version is `2.2.3` which is above the `2.2.2` version recommended for Rails 5.

**Ruby version:** `2.2.3p173`
**Rails version:** `5.0.0.beta1.1`
**RVM version:** `1.26.11`

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error was caused by the `web-console` gem as referenced here: [Error when running rails console](https://github.com/rails/web-console/issues/184). `web-console` was at version `3.1.0` at the time this was reported. The `3.0.0` version of `web-console` seemed not to have produced any errors when `rails console` was executed.

You'll need to ensure your version of `web-console` is `3.1.1` and greater as the issue has been fixed in the `3.1.1` version.

Comment: I'll do that. I have to wait for two days before I can.

Comment: +1 I had the same issue using `web-console 3.1.0` with Rails 4.2.5.1, and the linked Github thread assisted me.  A downgrade back to 3.0 got the console working again.

Comment: Rails 4.2.5.1 has same issue. But it can be fixed with updated version `3.1.1` of `web-console`, too.

Answer (score 0):

`gem install spring` worked for me.

My problem was:

```
/usr/local/bin/NMONMerge.rb:209:in `block in <main>': undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from /usr/local/bin/NMONMerge.rb:191:in `each'
from /usr/local/bin/NMONMerge.rb:191:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score -2):

**You need to install  spring  gem**

```
gem install spring  --pre
```